# Hangman - correct number of dashes won't display

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm a Javascript student working on my Hangman game. My loop to display the correct number of dashes for the secret word isn't working. It only displays one dash every time.
Help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    // array of letters to choose
    var alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Z"];

    $("#lettersRemaining").html(alphabet);


$("#newGame").click(function() {    // when user clicks on Start New Game button...

    //  array of words
    var wordCollection = ["mansion", "statue", "gorilla", "notebook", "smartphone", "illustration", "photo", "elegant", "arborist", "keyboard", "calendar", "capital", "textbook", "horrible", "library"];

    // randomly select a word from the wordCollection array
    var theWord = wordCollection[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordCollection.length)]; 
        console.log("theWord is ....");
        console.log(theWord);

    // Get index location of the word randomly selected above       -- Not sure I even need index..??
    var theWordIndex = wordCollection.indexOf(theWord);
        console.log("theWordIndex is ....");
        console.log(theWordIndex);

    // Get number of characters in word randomly selected above
    var theWordLength = theWord.length;
        console.log("theWordLength is ....");
        console.log(theWordLength);


    // display a dash equal to the theWordLength
    for (var i = theWordLength; i > 0; i--) 
    {
        $("#dashes").html(" - ");
    }
```

Comment: You're setting the HTML each time, not adding to it.

Comment: You are setting one single dash as the content of the element - multiple times. Either assemble the necessary number of dashes in a string variable first, and then assign that - or use innerHTML+=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here :
`$("#dashes").html(" - ");`

You're overriding the inner HTML of `#dashes` at every iteration. What you need is to "concatenate" (combine two strings together) the current content with the new dash.

On a more practical side, DOM accesses are VERY harmful for performance. You should generally not put them in loops. The best practice is to compute all DOM changes you can before executing them. In your case, I would prepare a `dashes` variable, then set the content of `#dashes` when the loop has finished executing.

Some helpful resources to get you started :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat

http://api.jquery.com/text/

http://api.jquery.com/html/